# Cast Values from a dictionary as they are put into an ArrayList?

Tags: vba

I'd like to export the data items in a Dictionary to an ArrayList so you can loop over them. I've done this in the past with this simple line of code:

```
return New ArrayList(DP.Tables(1).pRow.Values)
```

The problem is that the Values are typeless. Is there a way to cast them to a particular object type, in this case Account, as they are put into the ArrayList?

I suppose I could loop over them, but this may be a performance issue?

*UPDATE:* this is ultimately intended for consumption within a COM in VBA.

Comment: You should use generics.

Comment: Do they work in COM objects in VBA? I seem to recall they do not.

Comment: You're right; they don't.

Comment: You really should make clear what platform your using, before I waste time giving you an answer that wont work!

Comment: is "Account" a class? and what does it look like.

Comment: The Account class is Dictionary with a few custom methods.

Comment: I beleive you will need to write a custom function to parse the data and put it into the class.  There is no cast method that will do that for you.

Comment: Ok Sorcei, thanks. I suspected that but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything obvious! And DonA, that was useful code to know anyway.

Comment: Why cast the dictionary to an array instead of looping through the dictionary?

Comment: The Dictionary object contains two built-in functions that handle the OP's question. The Keys and Items functions each return an Array of the Dictionary's Keys or Items respectively. Thus, looping not required.